# Variable class properties due to specific constructor in C#

Tags: c#, class, properties

Suppose class A as:

```
public class A
{
    private string _str;
    private int _int;

    public A(string str)
    {
        this._str = str;
    }

    public A(int num)
    {
        this._int = num;
    }

    public int Num
    {
        get
        {
            return this._int;
        }
    }

    public string Str
    {
        get
        {
            return this._str;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to hide `Str` property when i construct class `A` as

```
new A(2)
```

and want to hide `Num` property when i construct class `A` as

```
new A("car").
```

What should i do?

Comment: You should say what your use case is, and then decide on an appropriate design for that use case. What you ask for is not only impossible but also goes against basic OO principles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That isn't possible with a single class. An `A` is an `A`, and has the same properties - regardless of how it is constructed.

You *could* have 2 *subclasses* of `abstract A`, and a factory method...

```
public abstract class A
{
    class A_Impl<T> : A
    {
        private T val;
        public A_Impl(T val) { this.val = val; }
        public T Value { get { return val; } }
    }
    public static A Create(int i) { return new A_Impl<int>(i); }
    public static A Create(string str) { return new A_Impl<string>(str); }
}
```

But : the caller *will not know about the value* unless they cast it.

Comment: Would you give an example or suggest an article regarding to this issue?

Comment: @petre well, I've added some code, but fundamentally you are trying to do something that is contrary to object orientation

Answer (score 2):

use generics

```
public class A<T>
{
    private T _value;

    public A(T value)
    {
        this._value= value;
    }

    public TValue
    {
        get
        {
            return this._value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: although this would also enable `new A(DateTime.Now)`for example, meaning the constructor takes any type.